# Accessing SQL insert function doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, c#-4.0, sqlconnection

That is my access code:

```
namespace DataBaseApp
{
        class DB_Access
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

            public DB_Access()                          
            {                    
                conn = DB_Connection.GetConnection();   // Bağlantıyı sağlamak için DB_Connection classından metodu aldım değere atadım //
            }               

            public void add_student(string RegNo, string FName, string LName, string Phone) // Burada programdan veritabanina nasil veri eklenir //
            {
                if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")  // State durum bildirir.Eğer Database akışı kapalıysa açalım //
                {
                    conn.Open();        
                }
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    newCmd.Connection = conn;

                    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student(RegNo,FName,LName,Phone) values(RegNo,FName,LName,Phone)";
                    newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }        
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Errorr " + Ex);        
                }        
            }        
         }
```

and this is connection code

```
namespace DataBaseApp
{
    class DB_Connection
    {
        public static SqlConnection NewCon; // Yeni bir bağlantıo oluşturma //
        public static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString; //App.config dosyasıyla bağlantı oluşturma //

        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()     //.config den gelen string file ile bağlantı kurulur //
        {
            NewCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            return NewCon;    
        }    
    }
```

When I run this this can't run `add_student` method ?? I completely change `app.config` file I think error not in `app.config`.

In fact this is windows form application of simple sql integration to c# but when I push add new student method program crashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Insert-SqlCommand, you're not passing the values.

So you should edit your code to this:

```
newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student(RegNo,FName,LName,Phone) values(@RegNo,@FName,@LName, @Phone)";
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo);
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName); 
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName); 
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
```

**Sidenote:** 
Also, edit the following code:

```
 if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
```

To this:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
```

Comment: how to like include add_student.RegNo ??

Comment: @crazy_tr What do you mean? Btw. I updated my answer to match your parameter values.